# winforms - datagridview row height doesn't resize when defaultcellstyle is set to wrapmode

Tags: winforms, datagridview

i have a datagrid that displays long text on couple columns. I have set the cells defaultcellstyle to wrap. This works but now the row height doesn't change to compensate for the wrapped text & the text is getting cut-off.

What am i missing?

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode to AllCells or DisplayedCells and it is done automatically.  More information about the various sizing options is available in this [MSDN Library article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b2wakt.aspx)